# 4th gen shuffle battery, no lights or charge

Tags: ipod, battery, charging

My 4th gen ipod has not been used for some time, I have a new usb to jack cable for charging it.

The shuffle shows no signs of life, no lights, when I plug it into the wall or computer(different docs, different computers). I left it to charge for a few hours, but nothing.

I followed some instructions on the trouble shooting pages of ipod shuffle... bla to nop avail.

Is the battery shot? Or are there solutions out there..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like a hardware issue, and you will probably do best to contact Apple.

I assume you have, but I would check the old cable (if it is still around and functioning), just to make sure that doesn't work as well. There is always a chance the new cable is somehow non-functional.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I'll take it to the shop to see what they say.  I imagine it's broken... ever the optimist I am

Comment: All the best to you. Hopefully it's an easy fix. Don't forget to accept my answer - if it answered your question.